# c# System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#

I'm making program that sends email with some data. I know that the `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException` exception means that number in the array/list doesn't exist, but i don't know what i coded wrongly.

Here's a code:

```
public void SendMail()
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path1);
    var lineCount = File.ReadLines(path1).Count();
    List<string> data = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++)
    {
       data[i] = sr.ReadLine(); //Error Comes here.
    }
    string finaldata = data[0] + "/n" + data[1] + "/n" + data[2] + "/n" + data[3] + "/n" + data[4] + "/n" + data[5] + "/n" +       
    data[6] + "/n" + data[7] + "/n" + data[8] + "/n" + data[9] + "/n" + data[10];
    var fromAddress = new MailAddress("tutorialvideohd@gmail.com", "From Name");
    var toAddress = new MailAddress("tutorialvideohd@example.com", "To Name");
    const string fromPassword = "*****";
    string subject = "Some Users Data.";
    string body = finaldata;

    var smtp = new SmtpClient
    {
       Host = "smtp.gmail.com",
       Port = 587,
       EnableSsl = true,
       DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
       UseDefaultCredentials = false,
       Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword)
    };

    using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
    {
        Subject = subject,
        Body = body
    })
    {
        smtp.Send(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: `List<string> data = new List<string>();` create empty list that doesn't have any elements. So when you try `data[i] =` it trows exception. You can fix it: `data.Add(sr.ReadLine())`

Comment: In think you mean "\n" (newline) instead of "/n" (slash followed by an n). However, according to RFC 2822, section 2 CRLF, i.e. "\r\n", should be used.

Comment: @MemesTV: what does the "/n" mean?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ArgumentOutOfRangeException on initialized List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236629/argumentoutofrangeexception-on-initialized-list)

Comment: @code4life `\n` is newline, it would be better to use `Environment.NewLine` which, at least in every environment I have used would be `\r\n` for carrage return, new line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this, it's only creating an empty list:

```
List<string> data = new List<string>();
```

So if you try to assign a value using an index, you're trying to assign a value to something that doesn't exist.

Instead you should `Add()` as follows:

```
data.Add(sr.ReadLine());
```

---

**EDIT:**

Also, unrelated to the question asked, but I don't see you closing the `StreamReader` you've opened, which is always a bad practice. I suggest, instead, using a `using` statement which will take care of the opening and closing of the `StreamReader` for you. Also, getting the `lineCount` is redundant, you could do something like this taking advantage of the fact that you don't need to set the number of items in a list in advance.

```
List<string> data = new List<string>();
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path1))
{
    while(!sr.EndOfStream)
        data.Add(sr.ReadLine()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have an empty list of strings, you can't fill `data` with by accessing the indexes, since those indexes don't yet exist. You have to use `data.Add(sr.ReadLine())` to create the new index and add the value in it.

```
string finaldata = data[0] + "/n" + data[1] + "/n" + data[2] + "/n" + data[3] + "/n" + data[4] + "/n" + data[5] + "/n" +       
data[6] + "/n" + data[7] + "/n" + data[8] + "/n" + data[9] + "/n" + data[10];
```

Hardcoded IDs will mean you need at least 11 items in the list and it will break if you have less. Why don't you do this instead?

```
string finalData = String.Join("/n", data);
```

This way it joins your list of strings, using the newline as a separator and doesn't matter if you have more or less items in the list.

Comment: @GeorgeAlexandria Yes, both parts need to be fixed, the finalData will still throw an exception if the stream didn't have 11 lines.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting an item in the array list that has not yet been initialized. Use the following line where the exception is thrown.

```
data.Add(sr.ReadLine());
```

Answer (score -1):

You are doing the same thing twice.

This block of code:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path1);
// ... you had some code here, but not relevant to the point...
for (int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++)
{
    data[i] = sr.ReadLine(); //Error Comes here.
}
```

Populates the list `data` with a bunch of strings.

This block of code:

```
var lineCount = File.ReadLines(path1).ToList();
```

Populates `lineCount` with exactly the list of strings that you're trying to fill into `data`.

So just do this:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path1);
var lineCount = File.ReadLines(path1).Count();
List<string> data = lineCount;
```

And get rid of this block of code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lineCount; i++)
{
    data[i] = sr.ReadLine(); //Error Comes here.
}
```

And notice how `data` is now properly filled in. You really don't need to have that `StreamReader` either, but hey, I don't want to rewrite your entire body of code at this point.

Key takeaway: read the documentation, try to understand what **each** function call is doing, especially the .NET Framework ones.

Comment: `.Count()` never returns a list of strings, it returns the number of in this case lines in the file being used for the stream reader. `lineCount` is an int not a list of strings.

Comment: @Andrew: yeah, I should have removed the `.Count()` and replaced with `.ToList()`.

Comment: No problem, part of why I have a dislike of `var` and even more so 'dynamic` in c# code, sure the system understands, but just looking at the code, you have to figure out the type, if it had said `int lineCount = File.ReadLines(path1).Count();` you would have caught it.

Comment: @Andrew: the fault wasn't with the `var`, it was with me, LOL. I was too lazy to back-check my code. At the end of the day, you can't blame the compiler or the language idiosyncracies, it's always myself.